# Not show form data in url django

Tags: python, django, passwords

I am creating a password reset form after a user is authenticated they are presented with the reset page where they can enter the username and new password. However once they have set this new data and click the submit button the data is shown in the url of the next page that is shown. How do I need to configure my application to not do this?

views.py

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = login(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.cleaned_data['username']
        passw = form.cleaned_data['password']
        if user and passw:
            #try the post to login
            r=validateUser(user,passw)
            if r:
                formReset = reset()
                return render(request, 'loggedin.html',{'form' : formReset})
            else:
                return render(request, 'index.html',{'form' : form})
else:
    form = login()
    loggedin(request)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form' : form})

def loggedin(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = reset(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.cleaned_data['username']
        newpassword = form.cleaned_data['newpassword']
        confirmnewpassword = form.cleaned_data['confirmnewpassword']
        if newpassword == confirmnewpassword:
            #passwords match
            val = resetpassword(user,newpassword)
        else:
            return render(request, 'loggedin.html', {"message" : 'Passwords do not match', 'form' : form})
else:
    return render(request, 'loggedin.html',{'form' : form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class login(forms.Form):
#class used for the login prompt
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'btn btn-lg btn-default'}),label='')
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'btn btn-lg btn-default'}),label='')


class reset(forms.Form):
#class used for inputs to reset password
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'btn btn-default'}),label='User Name')
newpassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'btn btn-default'}),label='New Password')
confirmnewpassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'btn btn-default'}),label='Confirm Password')
```

loggedin.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<form action="/" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>You are logged in</h1>
    {{ message }} </br>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" action="submit" value="Reset">
</div></form>{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how a GET action works. You should be using POST for this anyway.